# Exclude multiple values in a vector in a pipe

Tags: r, functional-programming, magrittr

I am looking for a more elegant way to exclude multiple values from a vector in a pipe. The code below achieves what I need, but is quite ugly. Could you think of an alternative?

```
values_to_exclude <- c("b", "d")
        
letters[1:5] %>%
    .[ !(. %in% values_to_exclude) ] # quite ugly
```

Comment: Does it have to be with pipes? `setdiff(letters[1:5], values_to_exclude)` Why won't this work with your use case?

Comment: It would certainly work. I usually create the "letters[1:5]" part as part of a longer pipe chunk, but letters[1:5] %>% setdiff(values_to_exclude) would certianly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use `purrr`, but how about something like this:

```
values_to_exclude <- c("b", "d")
letters[1:5] %>% setdiff(., values_to_exclude)
# [1] "a" "c" "e"
```

Comment: Great tip. Even better like this letters[1:5] %>% setdiff(values_to_exclude)

Answer (score 1):

The `magrittr` package comes with a whole set of convenience functions. For example, `extract`:

```
library(magrittr)
letters[1:5] %>%
    extract(!(. %in% values_to_exclude))
[1] "a" "c" "e"
```

---

However, in this case, you could use `base::subset` in the same way:

```
letters[1:5] %>%
   subset(!(. %in% values_to_exclude))
```

Comment: There is a specific `magrittr` operator equivalent to `%in%`: `letters[1:5] %>%
 extract(!is_in(., values_to_exclude))`.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to offer another `base R` solution:

```
letters[1:5][!letters[1:5] %in% values_to_exclude]
```

Since beauty is in the eye of the beholder... I think this is easier to interpret if you are going to reference past code. Though, I think some of the other solutions are more efficient and concise.

Comment: I agree code beauty is subjective, but to me this particular solution seems to be quite hard to read. Appreciate the effort though.